# Restrict DynamoDB attribute value (quantity , type Number) to pass a certain maximumQuantity in a Update expression

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

In short , I want to have something like :
"ConditionExpression": "totalquantity + :increment < maximumQuantity"

but since the + operator is no supported it cant be acheived.

Also I want to do it in a single Update operation and not do a get item before to do this calculation.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid doing a GetItem before you increment? Are your latency requirements really such that one round trip to DynamoDB is acceptable, but two is not? A round trip to DynamoDB is very fast. And can decrements happen, as well as increments?

Comment: Its actually a transactionwrite with two updates followed by a final get query to have latest item updates, So I wanted to reduce another GetItem before the transactionwrite.
Yes decrements can also work.